# Create a nested menu from an array

Tags: php, submenu

I am creating a function that should output a nested HTML menu from an array. I want to get the following output, but I get none:

**Desired output**

```
<ol class="sortable ui-sortable">
  <li id="list_77"><div>test1</div>
    <ol>
      <li id="list_78"><div>subtest1</div>
        <ol>
            <li id="list_79"><div>subtest1-1</div></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>               
  </li> 
</ol>
```

**My Data.**

*$item*

```
Array
(    
    [77] => Array
        (
            [menu_id] => 77
            [menu_name] => test1
            [menu_parent_id] => 0
            [menu_sort] => 1
            [menu_link] => 
            [menu_status] => 1
        )

    [78] => Array
        (
            [menu_id] => 78
            [menu_name] => subtest1
            [menu_parent_id] => 77
            [menu_sort] => 1
            [menu_link] => 
            [menu_status] => 1
        )

    [79] => Array
        (
            [menu_id] => 79
            [menu_name] => subtest1-1
            [menu_parent_id] => 78
            [menu_sort] => 1
            [menu_link] => 
            [menu_status] => 1
        )
)
```

**My Function**

```
function sub($list) {

    foreach($list as $key => $menu){            
        echo '<li class="menu_list" id="item_'.$menu['menu_id'].'">';
        echo '<div>'.$menu['menu_id'].'-'.$menu['menu_name'].'-'.$list[$menu['menu_id']]."==".$parent.'</div>';

        if($list[$key]['menu_parent_id']!=$parent){
            echo '<ol>';
            echo $list[$key]['menu_parent_id'];
            echo '</ol>';
        } else {
            sub($list);
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }

}
$item = array();
echo sub($item);
```

Comment: What fails in this code? Is there any error shown? The list isn't ordered correctly? Which is the output?

Comment: `$parent` is not defined, and you are treating `$list[$menu['menu_id']]` as a string. You should see errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some issues with recursion. You should pass to the `sub` function some context, i.e. for which menu item it should produce the sub-menu.

This also means that the function might not have to `echo` anything, i.e. when the passed menu item does not have any children.

So, for one, this means all your `echo` should be under some condition.

I would also suggest to make the function create and return an HTML string, which you can then `echo`. This makes the function more flexible to be used.

Here is the suggested code:

```
function sub($list, $parent_id = null) {
    $html = '';
    foreach ($list as $menu_id => $menu) {
        if ($list[$menu_id]['menu_parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
            $sub = sub($list, $menu_id);
            if ($sub != '') {
                // if there are children, wrap them in OL tag:
                $sub = "<ol>\n$sub</ol>\n";
            }
            // assemble HTML for this menu:
            $html .= "<li class='menu_list' id='item_{$menu['menu_id']}'>"
                  .  "<div>{$menu['menu_name']}</div>\n$sub</li>\n";
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Here is how to use it:

```
// test data
$item = Array
(    
    77 => Array
        (
            "menu_id" => 77,
            "menu_name" => 'test1',
            "menu_parent_id" => 0,
            "menu_sort" => 1,
            "menu_link" => null,
            "menu_status" => 1
        ),
    78 => Array
        (
            "menu_id" => 78,
            "menu_name" => 'subtest1',
            "menu_parent_id" => 77,
            "menu_sort" => 1,
            "menu_link" => null,
            "menu_status" => 1,
        ),
    79 => Array
        (
            "menu_id" => 79,
            "menu_name" => 'subtest1-1',
            "menu_parent_id" => 78,
            "menu_sort" => 1,
            "menu_link" => null,
            "menu_status" => 1
        )
);

// Get complete output (no need to pass second argument)
echo sub($item);
```

Output is as follows:

```
<li class='menu_list' id='item_77'><div>test1</div>
<ol>
<li class='menu_list' id='item_78'><div>subtest1</div>
<ol>
<li class='menu_list' id='item_79'><div>subtest1-1</div>
</li>
</ol>
</li>
</ol>
</li>
```

Comment: @trincot the output of your function ain't correct, the li elements are not closed.

Comment: @ThomasScheffer, thanks for spotting this in my 2.5 year old answer :) Fixed now.

Comment: It showed up on the interesting tab for top question just now, guess because of the previous comment. np anyway :D